# Trying to create a simple logic app using the SQL Connector

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a simple Logic App

- I wanted to add an SQL connector...so I provided my connection info to an Azure SQL database that is in the same region as my test logic app. It went away for at least 3 minutes and came back saying that the connection could not have been made. So I might have typed something wrong.....but I could not find a way to fix what I typed. There is no way to edit the connection properties anymore. The only I could proceed was to delete the connector from the resource group and try again.
- However deleting the connector was not a simple task....when i selected the connector from the resource group....I kept on getting errors like 'unable to locate extension 'Microsoft_Azure_Microservices' and sometimes 'Error loading tile'. Anyway, I must have tried at least 5-6 times and it finally worked. I  deleted the connector and started over.
- The second attempt, I was able to create a connector...but I must not have provided a poll query ...so it said there is no trigger action and I had to go through the above steps all over again.
- The third attempt...I was able to create an SQL connector with a trigger (by providing both a data available and a poll queries) and I added an Office 365 connector. I ran it.....I was expecting to receive only 3 emails, but I received about 150 and going...then I had to disable it! So I wanted to check the queries (data available and poll) to make sure that I have the update statements coded correctly...but again...there is no way to do this. If I go to the resource manager, select the connector and try to perhaps get to the settings, I get the above errors....quite frustrating.

Can you please give me some pointers to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting.  Understand your frustration on where it is getting stuck.

To edit that settings after deployment, go in Azure to Browse -> API Apps -> Microsoft SQL Connector -> click the link under "host" or "API App Host" -> Settings -> Application Settings

Halfway down that blade you should see all of your provision settings for the API App.

As for why your app is infinitely looping, the [SQL Connector](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-sql/) Poll Query requires you to write back some value (or delete rows) so that rows won't show up twice.  In other words you need to write a query in a way that the API App knows if it has read the row before.  The sample Poll Query is

```
SELECT *, GetData() as 'PollTime' FROM [Order]
WHERE OrderStatus = 'ProcessedForCollection'
ORDER BY Id DESC;
UPDATE [Order] SET OrderStatus = 'ProcessedForFrontDesk'
    WHERE Id =
    (SELECT Id FROM [Order] WHERE OrderStatus = 'ProcessedForCollection' ORDER BY Id DESC)
```

With the availability query returning

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Order] WHERE OrderStatus = 'ProcessedForCollection'
```

Hope that makes sense.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Wow...it is really hidden. Hopefully it will be more obvious in the future. Yes..I understand there is a problem in the update query and this is what I wanted to fix and hence I needed the settings.

Comment: I now got everything working including custom API App. Thanks for your help. I think this platform has a great potential...however...I feel the new Azure portal is a little slow and cumbersome especially for the logic app designer.